# Rails external js function does not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following form:

```
<%= form_for @question, {:as => :question, :method => :post, :url => {:action => :multiple_choice}, :html => {:onsubmit=> "return checkAnswers();"}, :class => "form-inline"} do |f| %>
```

on submit the checkAnswers() JS function should be called and do some checks.

If I have this function inside the html.erb it works fine. ... but when I set it in public/javascript/myJSfunctions.js it dosn't work.

The js file is included in layout. what could be the problem?

function checkAnswers(){

```
var emptyStatus = false;

// prueft ob es leere antworten gibt - diese sind nicht zulaessig
$(".answerinput").each(function(){
    if ($(this).val == "" || $(this).val() == " " || $(this).html() == " " || $(this).val() == ""){
        $(".modal-title").html("Error");
        $(".modal-body").html("Leere Antwort moeglichkeit unzulaessig");
        $("#modalbox").modal("show");
        emptyStatus = true;
    }
});

if (emptyStatus){
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: You should include your js file here

Comment: try to place your javascript file in app/assets/javascripts and don't forget to require it in application.js

Comment: don't have a application.js 

in this js file are several other function they all work perfect

Comment: have you tried to wrap your code in `document.ready`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using jQuery and Turbolinks? I had the same problem with my javascript code and the solution was to use the gem 'jquery-turbolinks'. You also need to require it in the correct order in your application.js:

//=require jquery

//=require jquery.turbolinks

//= All your other scripts

//=require turbolinks (this should be the last one!)

Comment: Have you tried:

    <%= javascript_include_tag "javascript/myJSfunctions.js" %>

Answer (score 1):

seems you are using older version of rails may be < rails3 so the application.js file is not there.

include it through your layout.
Add following line to your views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "myJSfunctions.js" %>
```

Comment: try placing javascript alert and see if it get called. change onsubmit to  {:onsubmit=> "alert(1);"}. If you do not get this alert means you are doing something with wrong syntax.